# Shortest window in all numbers appear

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minimum Window for the given numbers in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382757/minimum-window-for-the-given-numbers-in-an-array)

I wanted to know the approach that should be applied here. We have an array that contains numbers from 0 to n. We have to find the smallest window in which all numbers from 1 to n appear.

eg:

1 0 2 3 1 4 0

Answer should be 2 3 1 4

1 3 1 4 0 1 2 0 3 2 4 1

Answer should be 3 2 4 1

If there are many such windows possible, then the window appearing first should be printed.

Comment: It's not a programming question! By the way simply use "Dynamic Programming" method!